# MySQL select row with and without relation

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

Let say I have 2 mysql tables 'movies' and 'seen'

If a user already saw a movie there is a record in the 'seen' table, with his userID and the movieID

I have to print **ALL** the movies, and then if the user already saw the movie print "already watched" otherwise "to watch".

At this time I use PHP with 2 seprate queries:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM movies" );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
  echo $row['movie_name'];
  $res2 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM seen WHERE userID = '$uid' AND movieID = '$row[id]' LIMIT 1" );
  if( mysql_num_rows( $res2 ) == 1 ) { echo "already watched"; } else { echo "to watch"; }
}
```

**There is a way to do that with ONE single query?**

*With JOIN on "movies.id = seen.movieID" it only print the wahtched movies, with "WHERE movies.id NOT IN ( SELECT seen.movieID FROM seen WHERE seen.userID = '$uid' )" it only print the not watched..*

Comment: We just don't do this anymore. Stop using PHP's mysql_ API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this cases you can use from LEFT JOIN, in the left join you can see data which is on table first and is not on second table.

```
SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN seen ON movies.id = seen.movieID
```

if data of seen table was on result data exist if not user did not seen.

Also you can use UNION in your solution and merge to query

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sub query which aggregates the number of times a user has seen a movie:

```
SELECT m.userid, m.movieid, 
  case when s.seencount is null then 0 else 1 end as seenmovie
FROM movies m left join 
    (SELECT movieid, userid, count (id) 
    FROM seen
    GROUP BY movieid, userid) as s on m.movieid = s.movieid and m.userid = s.userid
```

This will also handle cases where users have watched a movie more than once

I'm on a mobile device so apologies if any typos but you should get the idea

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `movies` 
LEFT JOIN ( select movieName,'Watched' as w from seen where userId='$uid' ) s 
on s.movieId=movies.movieId
```

Will give watched when movie is watched otherwise it will give NULL